# Sett's Calling Card

Tags: league-of-legends

Regarding the hidden mission **Sett's Calling Card**:

Can you guys describe the actual mission requirement? I heard many version of it, getting **S+ rank**, get **PentaKill** or X numbers of **FirstBlood**.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official confirmation yet, but general consensus seems to agree on 10 times first blood in PvP matches.

[Here is more discussion on the subject](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/eb8u8h/how_to_get_setts_calling_card/)